# WooCommerce - Overwrite Single product Tabs H2

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce gives the tabs in a Single Product page H2 heading by default.
As these headings are not really relevant for my rankings I would rather make them H3 or H4.

How could I overwrite the template so that I can change it to H3?

I have looked at https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/ but I can't figure it out.

Should  I copy the complete original template file. And then just change H2 to H3? Put this into a subfolder?

Comment: Update: I noticed that some fields still have H2 headers. I tried to find them but cannot figure out in which files they are. How can you find with file to edit?

For example, under the review tab there is a header " xx reviews for product x" which is in h2.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the latest WooCommerce and you are not using any other plugins or code to alter the tabs, create the following folder structure in your child theme:

`/child-theme/woocommerce/single-product/tabs`

Now copy the two files `additional-information.php` and `description.php` in the 'tabs' folder. You will find the following code in those files:

```
<h2><?php echo $heading; ?></h2>
```

Simply change the `<h2></h2>` to `<h3></h3>` or `<h4></h4>`

Do not edit core files of any plugin for your changes will be lost when the plugin is updated.

Hope this helps.

Update: For reviews tab, copy `woocommerce/ templates/single-product-reviews.php` to your child theme under `woocommerce/single-product-reviews.php` and edit that file.

Find:
`<h2 class="woocommerce-Reviews-title"></h2>`

Edit the `<h2></h2>` with `<h3></h3>` or `<h4></h4>`, same as above.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @dzinee I have updated the answer above for the update you made in your question.